# Swift show view controller from a completion handler

Tags: xcode, swift, presentviewcontroller, completionhandler

I have a view controller with a function "CV" in it which constructs the views content. the function CV has a completion handler which returns itselve as the variable V. What I would now want to do is when I create a new Instance of that view that is shows V like so :

```
func S0000 (VD0000: O0001) {
    (self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("V0005") as! V0005).Cv (VD0000){ (V) -> Void in
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
            self.presentViewController(V, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

This returns the error that V == nil which I dont understand why. I found out that If I write it like this :

```
func S0000 (VD0000: O0001) {
    let V = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("V0005") as! V0005
    self.showViewController(V, sender: self)
    V.Cv (VD0000){ (V) -> Void in
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
        }
    }
}
```

than it works, but this defeats the purpose which is to onley present V when its constuction is completed.

How could I do this ?

Comment: I do not know where to start: variables and functions should start with a lower case letter `vd0000 `, `cv` and `v` instead of `VD0000`, `V` and `Cv`. Names in general should be meaningful, not numbered - not `VD0000`, `O0001`, `S0000`, `V0005` - I 10000% guarantee you that nobody other than you can understand your code.

Comment: Yes I Know, I tought it to myselfe so I started out wrong and cant realy get rid of it, but ill trye.

Comment: Rewrite everything. You won't be able to handle that mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first function, your instance of the view controller goes out of scope as soon as the function is finished so it is no longer there when the completion handler is called.

[EDIT]

You could have a variable named preraringViewController:UIViewController?  in the class containing S000 and use it to keep a reference to your view controller while .cv is preparing it.

```
var preraringViewController:UIViewController? = nil
func S0000 (VD0000: O0001) 
{
   preraringViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("V0005")
   (preraringViewController as! V0005).Cv (VD0000)
    { (V) -> Void in
       NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
        self.presentViewController(V, animated: true, completion: nil)
       preraringViewController  = nil
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How could I prevent this from happening ?

Comment: You'll have to keep an instance variable in a scope that is wider than the S000 function.   I edited my answer to give an example.